# Why am I having an error to install a Keras package in PyCharm?

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, coding-style, artificial-intelligence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtDoz.png)

I have installed the keras (see below box, but it turns out I cannot import the sequential, dense and lstm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install `tensorflow` package https://www.tensorflow.org/install